# Adding a URL Prefix

Tags: 7, i18n-l10n, views, uri

We currently have a product catalog that has a URL structure like this:

- www.domain.com/catelog/product-category
- www.domain.com/catelog/product-category/product-1

going forward we would like to offer a slightly different catalog with the same categories but a subset of products to the EU. The wish is to structure the URLs like this:

- www.domain.com/eu/catelog/product-category
- www.domain.com/eu/catelog/product-category/product-1

As we already have all sorts custom templates set up, I was hoping to just sneak in a prefix somehow, but not sure the best approach to take…

I guess the proper way to do this would be to set up View Pages and contextual filters, but that would mean recreating all my custom node templates as view templates.

It’s tempting to set it up as a multi lingual site, although we are not translating the URL structure matches what we are looking for. I think a custom language of "eu" would handle the prefix stuff i'm looking for

Any ideas appreciated.